# How to get div tag(runat="server") value in asp.net codebehind as a innerhtml format?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, html

I declared div tag as following:

```
<div id="txt" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
</div>
```

I am using txt as like textbox. I have to get whatever that i entered into the "txt" in codebehind as innerhtml format. I tried following code but it shows only innerhtml tag only. It doesnt shows the value.

```
objPLEmailTemplate.EmailTemplateBody = txt.InnerText;
```

Please help me

Comment: are you getting value in `InnerHtml`?

Comment: The div is declared as _what_? It should be a `HtmlGenericControl`. It has `InnerText` and `InnerHtml` properties, both are set and retained across postbacks. Tested it with ASP.NET 4.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to edit `txt` div's content on client and pass it to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using hidden field using javascript:

function GetDivHTML() 
{ 
     var hdnDiv = document.getElementById('HdnDivContent');
     var content = document.getElementById('txt'); 
     hdnDiv.value = content.innerHTML; 
}

Store the value in hidden and then assign the hidden value to my variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
objPLEmailTemplate.EmailTemplateBody = txt.InnerHtml;
```